# UI Testing: How to query for picker value in a form

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to write a UI test for a form containing a picker. I would like to check whether the selected value of the picker is "2" or "2 Coins" respectively after launching the app.

I'm able to tap the picker and select a new value:

```
func testExample() throws {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
    
    app.tables.buttons["Coins"].tap()
    app.tables.buttons["1 Coin"].tap()
}
```

But I don't know how to check which value is selected.

Here's the view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var coins = 2

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Picker("Coins", selection: $coins) {
                    Text("1 Coin").tag(1)
                    Text("2 Coins").tag(2)
                    Text("3 Coins").tag(3)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to check value? The expression `app.tables.buttons["1 Coin"].tap()` checks result of selection by itself, ie. if there is no "1 Coin" this expression would fail test.

Comment: @Asperi: This is correct, but that's only in that simplified example code. For my real code, I'm setting an accessible identifier on the picker and using this for tapping the button.